# How can I reprogram feature key F12 of HP ZBook

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, hp

HP ZBook Power 15.6 inch G9 Mobile Workstation PC with Azerty keyboard.

In between the feature key for "flight mode" and "prt scr" there's a key with 3 diamonds (also F12 key), of which the middle diamond partially covers the two diamonds on either side.

Its function is to launch several applications at the same time. If I pushed this key for the first time, I could set it up so that it launches MS Outlook and MS Teams at the same time. So far, so good. But how can I change it (e.g. add a 3rd application)?

[image: Feature key on top row of keyboard with F12]

Answer (score 2):

That key/icon is called the **HP Programmable Key**.

You should be able to manage it inside the (preinstalled) **MyHP** app on your laptop, if you can't find it you can try installing the [**HP Programmable Key**](https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9MW15F21R5G8) app from the Microsoft store.